# Javascript get day from HTML date string

Tags: javascript

I have a div with a date within it as follows:

```
<div id="am-event-sub-info">
 <div> February 27, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to extract the date from this string and then get the day?

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, getting the string? Turning it into a date? Getting the day? (And by day, do you mean "Monday" or "14th" etc)

Comment: strugling to get the day e.g Monday from this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you don't mind that Februrary 27th 2021 is a Saturday...

```js
console.log(
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { weekday: 'long'}).format(
    new Date(
        document.querySelector('#am-event-sub-info > div')
            .innerHTML
            .split(' - ')[0]  // only interested in the "February 27, 2021 11:30 am" part
    )
  )
);
```

```html
<div id="am-event-sub-info">
 <div> February 27, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
</div>
```

Update: Add the "day" after date in a div

```js
var day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { weekday: 'long'}).format(
  new Date(
      document.querySelector('#am-event-sub-info > div')
          .innerHTML
          .split(' - ')[0]  // only interested in the "February 27, 2021 11:30 am" part
  )
);

document.querySelector('#am-event-sub-info').innerHTML += '<div class="day">'+day+'</div>';
```

```css
.day { color: green; }
```

```html
<div id="am-event-sub-info">
 <div> February 27, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. How would i actually show the day Saturday in HTML?

Comment: @user38208 where do you want to show it in HTML? do you want to overwrite the current date or do you have a placeholder somewhere or just append after the div?

Comment: @append after div in a new div called day?

Comment: @user38208 updated the answer. for the future, make sure to ask only one question at the time and also add code of what you have tried. You will not always find someone like me doing your homework